# Perl do input one char from stdin

Tags: perl, input

How can Perl do input from `stdin`, one char like

```
readline -N1
```

does?

Comment: Hi , try to ```use Term::ReadKey;```  or perldoc Term::ReadKey.

Comment: Do you mean read one *character* from stdin like ksh93 / bash do with `IFS= read -r -N1` (assuming that's what you meant by `readline -N1`; though note that they also change the tty settings when stdin is a tty) or read one *byte* (C `char` type).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with the base perl distribution, no need to install extra packages:

```
use strict;
sub IO::Handle::icanon {
        my ($fh, $on) = @_;
        use POSIX;
        my $ts = new POSIX::Termios;
        $ts->getattr(fileno $fh) or die "tcgetattr: $!";
        my $f = $ts->getlflag;
        $ts->setlflag($on ? $f | ICANON : $f & ~ICANON);
        $ts->setattr(fileno $fh) or die "tcsetattr: $!";
}

# usage example
# a key like `Left` or `á` may generate multiple bytes
STDIN->icanon(0);
sysread STDIN, my $c, 256;
STDIN->icanon(1);
# the read key is in $c
```

Reading just one byte may not be a good idea because it will just leave garbage to be read later when pressing a key like `Left` or `F1`. But you can replace the `256` with `1` if you want just that, no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

`<STDIN>` will read stdin one *byte* (C `char` type, which is not the same as a *character* which these days are typically made of several bytes except for those in the US-ASCII charset) at a time from stdin if the record separator is set to a reference to the number 1.

```
$ echo perl | perl -le '$/ = \1; $a = <STDIN>; print "<$a>"'
<p>
```

Note that underneath, it may read (consume) more than one byte from the input. Above, the next `<STDIN>` within `perl` would return `<e>`, but possibly from some large buffer that was read beforehand.

```
$ echo perl | (perl -le '$/ = \1; $a = <STDIN>; print "<$a>"'; wc -c)
<p>
0
```

Above, you'll notice that `wc` didn't receive any input as it had all already been consumed by `perl`.

```
$ echo perl | (PERLIO=raw perl -le '$/ = \1; $a = <STDIN>; print "<$a>"'; wc -c)
<p>
4
```

This time, `wc` got 4 bytes (`e`, `r`, `l`, `\n`) as we told `perl` to use raw I/O so the `<STDIN>` translates to a `read(0, bud, 1)`.

Instead of `<STDIN>`, you can use `perl`'s `read` with the same caveat:

```
$ echo perl | (perl -le 'read STDIN, $a, 1; print "<$a>"'; wc -c)
<p>
0
$ echo perl | (PERLIO=raw perl -le 'read STDIN, $a, 1; print "<$a>"'; wc -c)
<p>
4
```

Or use `sysread` which is the true wrapper for the raw `read()`:

```
$ echo perl | (perl -le 'sysread STDIN, $a, 1; print "<$a>"'; wc -c)
<p>
4
```

To read one *character* at a time, you need to read one byte at a time until the end of the character.

You can do it for UTF-8 encoded input (in locales using that encoding) in `perl` with `<STDIN>` or `read` (not `sysread`) with the `-C` option, including with `raw` `PERLIO`:

```
$ echo été | (PERLIO=raw perl -C -le '$/ = \1; $a = <STDIN>; print "<$a>"'; wc -c)
<é>
4
$ echo été | (PERLIO=raw perl -C -le 'read STDIN, $a, 1; print "<$a>"'; wc -c)
<é>
4
```

With `strace`, you'd see `perl` does two `read(0, buf, 1)` system calls underneath to read that 2-byte `é` character.

Like with ksh93 / bash's `read -N` (or zsh's `read -k`), you can get surprises if the input is not properly encoded in UTF-8:

```
$ printf '\375 12345678' | (PERLIO=raw perl -C -le 'read STDIN, $a, 1; print "<$a>"'; wc -c)
<� 1234>
4
```

`\375` (`\xFD`) would normally be the first byte of the encoding of a 6 byte character in UTF-8¹, so `perl` reads all 6 bytes here even though the second to sixth can't possibly be part of that character as they don't have the 8<sup>th</sup> bit set.

Note that when stdin is a tty device, `read()` will not return until the terminal at the other end sends a LF (`eol`), CR (which is by default converted to LF), or `eof` (usually `^D`) or `eol2` (usually not defined) character as configured in the tty line discipline (like with the `stty` command) as the tty driver implements its own internal line editor allowing you to edit what you type before pressing enter.

If you want to read the byte(s) that is(are) sent for each key pressed by the user there, you'd need to disable that line editor (which bash/ksh93's `read -N` or `zsh`'s `read -k` do when stdin is a tty), see [@guest's answer](/a/678823) for details on how to do that.

---

<sup>¹ While now Unicode restricts codepoints to up to 0x10FFFF which means UTF-8 encodings have at most 4 bytes, UTF-8 was originally designed to encode code points up to 0x7fffffff (up to 6 byte encoding) and `perl` extends it to up to 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (13 byte encoding)</sup>